# How can I avoid including same day HLC prices in ADX function

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to use the ADX function (TTR package).
I use the following syntax but I'm not sure if the current day prices are part of the formula.If they are then I can't use this function for prediction.Is there a way to avoid the current day prices with ADX.
Here is the line of code I use:

```
AMZN$ADX14<-ADX(HLC(AMZN),n = 14, maType="EMA", wilder=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code, yes the close price on a given timestamp is used in calculating the corresponding ADX value on that timestamp.

Based on your description, it seems like you want to use `lag` 1 values of the ADX, which you could achieve this way (for n = 6 for simplicity):

```
AMZN$ADX6 <- ADX(HLC(AMZN),n = 6, maType="EMA", wilder=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
AMZN$ADX6lag1 <- lag.xts(ADX(HLC(AMZN),n = 6, maType="EMA", wilder=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE))

head(AMZN, 13)
           AMZN.Open AMZN.High AMZN.Low AMZN.Close AMZN.Volume AMZN.Adjusted      DIp      DIn        DX     ADX6    DIp.1    DIn.1      DX.1 ADX6lag1
2007-01-03     38.68     39.06    38.05      38.70    12405100         38.70       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2007-01-04     38.59     39.14    38.26      38.90     6318400         38.90       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2007-01-05     38.72     38.79    37.60      38.37     6619700         38.37       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2007-01-08     38.22     38.31    37.17      37.50     6783000         37.50       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2007-01-09     37.60     38.06    37.34      37.78     5703000         37.78       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2007-01-10     37.49     37.70    37.07      37.15     6527500         37.15       NA       NA        NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2007-01-11     37.17     38.00    37.17      37.40     6465600         37.40  7.54711 23.32760 51.111380       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA
2007-01-12     37.36     38.21    37.27      38.20     4466400         38.20 10.33458 18.93201 29.376237       NA  7.54711 23.32760 51.111380       NA
2007-01-16     38.40     38.89    37.97      38.66     5643700         38.66 21.85520 15.50147 17.008279       NA 10.33458 18.93201 29.376237       NA
2007-01-17     38.70     39.00    37.78      37.88     5026800         37.88 16.96372 15.51769  4.451876       NA 21.85520 15.50147 17.008279       NA
2007-01-18     37.50     37.65    36.72      36.98     9105000         36.98 13.51296 30.94944 39.216234       NA 16.96372 15.51769  4.451876       NA
2007-01-19     36.69     37.48    36.60      37.02     6095900         37.02 11.40158 28.24434 42.482962 30.60783 13.51296 30.94944 39.216234       NA
2007-01-22     37.65     37.90    36.80      36.95     8317000         36.95 16.48641 22.88154 16.244505 28.21394 11.40158 28.24434 42.482962 30.60783
```

On timestamp `2007-01-22`, you could use `ADX6lag1 = 30.60783` (which was actually computed on `2007-01-19` to predict the close on that bar of `36.95`.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the current date before you run `ADX` by using
`getSymbols("AMZN",to=Sys.Date()-1)`

Comment: Because it will take all daily data one day back but all calculation will be also one day back so again we will have HLC data of the same date as the target date. The Close of the HLC will still be the Close of the target date so it will be kind of a future value that we can't have in a prediction model.